# How to show span in centered html table cell without shifting all of the other text

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, center, show

I have some text inside a html table cell.  The text is centered.

```
 <td colspan=7>This is the text<span >Loading . . .</span></td>
```

I want to show and hide then span that is sitting at the end of the text but when I do that all of the text shifts over to the left as it now recenters the entire visible text.

Is there anyway to show and hide the span just as the end of the text (without shifting and recentering all of the info ?)

Comment: can you setup a http://jsfiddle.net/ for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Centered span only:

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>
          This is the text
          <span style="display:block;width:100px;margin:0px auto;">Loading . . .</span>
     </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set span style as `"float:right"`

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is to add the css style `visibility: hidden;` to your span. As per the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/visufx.html#visibility):

> Invisible boxes still affect layout (set the 'display' property to 'none' to suppress box generation altogether). Values have the following meanings:

This means that your table layout (column width) will not change when you hide the span.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged this as jquery and haven't posted any code. so I assume you are using `.text()` method to achieve this, I would say use `.html()` method instead.